# Jitterbit project + Git + Continuous integration

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, salesforce, jitterbit

In our project we are using Jitterbit as a proxy between two systems - our Salesforce application and one third party service (we are using web services integration), and Jitterbit-part of our solution contains some business-logic (it's runned on a schedule hourly). Our team are actively working on the project and we are often modifying Jitterbit-part.

So, we are looking for abilities to improve our development process with help of Git and Continuous integration, especially for Jitterbit project (Salesforce part of a project are already using it). So, we have two issues here:

- We know that we can export Jitterbit project and put it to Git repository, but this export process always generate a lot of rubbish (some UIDs and other such stuff which is not directly related to our changes in the project). This makes it difficult clearly to observe changes in each commit.
- We didn't find any abilities to setup any CI tool (Jenkins, Travis-ci) for building and deploying to cloud a Jitterbit project automatically (It seems to me, there is no such option in Jitterbit at all, but hope I'm wrong).

Can anybody with such experience help me, please?

Comment: As of Jitterbit 9.3, these problems still exist.  Yes you can create a GIT repo on top of the project directory, but you MUST include the cache folder ("binary" JARS) or delete it after rollback, otherwise when you rollback to a previous commit, Jitterbit will not actually use your source code but what is in the cache.  Clutch.

Comment: @Shane actually, if you have a Jitterbit licence, you can try to discuss this case with their support (and share this question with them), possibly it will help to change something :)

Comment: I spend a lot of time on calls with their support, sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it should be possible:
Assuming you are running on Harmony (ie v8+), you should be able to monitor/check-in (ie via Git) your local Projects folder (usually under Documents/JitterbitStudio or [YourUsername]/JitterbitStudio) or any set of the specific projects there. 
Similarly, Studio v8+ provides command-line support to allow for (automated) deploys (and more), so you can set-up your CI/CD tool (ie Jenkins) to be fully integrated with it.

You will probably want some more guidance around the process (ie exclusion rules, etc.), so remember that Jitterbit has an official and free unlimited support - just email support@jitterbit.com from your work email and they should get you going from there. You can share any general feedback with them as well, ie perhaps the need for CLI support for CI or more thorough official documentation to be posted on https://success.jitterbit.com, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As for placing Jitterbit-project under source control system, the main issue - each next time when I export jitterbit project and try to see diffs (even if I changed some small item of the project) I see a lot of changes that are not related directly to my modification (changes in files structure, changed UID, etc). That is all very much prevents to track what was actually changed.

Comment: As for CLI of Jitterbit studio, we will try it to use, thanks.